# Получить выборку пользователей по релевантности ответов на пройденное тестирование

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста с составлением SQL запроса!

В PHP скрипт передаётся 2 параметра:

- `subject_id` - ID темы тестирования;
- `user_id` - ID пользователя, который прошел тестирование и по отношению к которому нужно производить расчёт релевантности;

Пользователей которые прошли тестирование будет много, по этому запрос очень желательно сделать максимально оптимизированым.

В результате нужно получить выборку пользователей, отсортированных по реливантности ответов на тему тестирования.

**Таблица с темами тестов (subjects):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Таблица с тестами (tests):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Таблица с вариантами ответов на тест (options):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Таблица с ответами на каждый из тестов (answers):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что такое релевантность и какой запрос уже удалось составить вам

Comment: @Mike пока что никакой не удалось составить :) не приходилось сталкиваться с подобными запросами. Если говорить прямо, то даже мыслей нету толковых. Релевантность - в данном случае я представляю как целое число определяющее кол-во одинаковых ответов на тему теста для каждого пользователя в выборке. Т.е. к примеру, для темы есть 3 теста с несколькими вариантами ответов для каждого из тестов, пользователь "А" в тестах выбрал варианты [1,3,2], пользователь "Б" выбрал [2,3,2] - в данном случае значение релевантности для пользователя "Б" будет "2", т.к. последние 2 ответа совпадают, а первый - нет.

Comment: А сделать запрос который для заданного пользователя просто выберет все его ответы на заданную тему можете ? А то как то по картинкам составлять запрос не имея БД неудобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение задачи оказалось не таким сложным как я предполагал. Стоило немного пошевелить мозгами и всё разрешилось.

```
# ID пользователя, по отношению к которому нужно вычислять релевантность
SET @USER_ID = 1;
# ID темы тестирования
SET @SUBJECT_ID = 1;

select 
    u.*,
    /* подсчёт релевантности */
    (
        select 
            count(*)
        from
            answers as sa
        where
            sa.subject_id = @SUBJECT_ID
                and
            sa.option_id = ame.option_id
                and
            sa.user_id = u.id
    ) as rel

from users as u

/* получаем ответы пользователя с которыми нужно сравнивать */
join answers as ame on
    ame.subject_id = @SUBJECT_ID
        and
    ame.user_id = @USER_ID

/* получаем записи ответов всех пользователей по теме тестирования */
join answers as a on
    a.subject_id = @SUBJECT_ID
and
    a.user_id = u.id
/* исключаем пользователя из выборки, с которым нужно сравнивать */
and
    a.user_id != @USER_ID

group by 
    u.id

# сортировка по релевантности
order by
    rel desc
```